# Excel Upload API Documentation with Spring-doc

Tags: excel, spring, asciidoc, spring-restdocs

I am having a Spring REST API which upload a Excel file to server.I need to write a API documentation with spring and AsciiDoc . I tried to write documentation following way but in documentation HTML it shows the encoded characters from excel.

```
        final URL resource = MYClass.class.getResource("/excel/excel.xls");
        final File file = new File(resource.toURI());
        final FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        final MockMultipartFile fstmp = new MockMultipartFile("file", file.getName(), "multipart/form-data", fileInputStream);

        UriComponentsBuilder url= uri.path("/api/v1/uploadExcel")
            .queryParam("file", fstmp);

        document.snippets(
            requestParameters(
                parameterWithName("file").description("Excel file to upload")
            )
        );
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload(url.toUriString()).file(fstmp)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

This Code works perfect but generates documention in following way.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of different things that you could do:

One option is to send some dummy data to your controller for the purposes of documentation. Rather than sending an actual XLS file, you could send the String `<<binary XLS data>>`, or similar. This approach requires you to be able to mock out whatever your controller's using to process the XLS data so that it can cope with receiving data that isn't actually an XLS file.

Another option is to use an [`OperationPreprocessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/api/org/springframework/restdocs/operation/preprocess/OperationPreprocessor.html). This allows you to send a "correct" request to your controller but to then modify it prior to it being documented. You could write a preprocessor that modifies the content of the multipart upload:

```
final class PartContentModifyingPreprocessor extends OperationPreprocessorAdapter {

    private final OperationRequestPartFactory partFactory = new OperationRequestPartFactory();

    private final OperationRequestFactory requestFactory = new OperationRequestFactory();

    @Override
    public OperationRequest preprocess(OperationRequest request) {
        List<OperationRequestPart> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (OperationRequestPart part : request.getParts()) {
            parts.add(this.partFactory.create(part.getName(),
                    part.getSubmittedFileName(), "<<binary data>>".getBytes(),
                    part.getHeaders()));
        }
        return this.requestFactory.create(request.getUri(), request.getMethod(),
                request.getContent(), request.getHeaders(), request.getParameters(),
                parts);

    }
}
```

You can find more information about customising requests and responses using preprocessors in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current/reference/html5/#customizing-requests-and-responses).